# Persistently write to a file from windows kernel driver

Tags: windows, kernel, wdk, wdm

Hi I'm new to kernel level programming and trying to build a simple log writing driver. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a persistent driver  will write referred text every predefined interval to a file in system path. (I'm not familiar IRQ hooking yet)

I have following globals for timing

```
// Timer 
PKTIMER pTimer = NULL; // Pointer to the timer
PKDPC pDpcObject = NULL; // Pointer to the DPC
#define IDLE_INTERVAL (10000)
```

I call following code in the DriverEntry (However, problem with following code is its writing feature fails when computer restarted) Could someone suggest a fix ? Should it be called by IRQ Major call ?

```
while(1)
    {

        if (pTimer == NULL) // if timer object does not exist:
        {
            // Allocate memory for the object timer
            pTimer = (PKTIMER) ExAllocatePool (NonPagedPool, sizeof (KTIMER));
            KeInitializeTimer (pTimer); // Initialize the timer object
            // Allocate memory for the DPC object and initialize it
            pDpcObject = (PKDPC) ExAllocatePool (NonPagedPool, sizeof (KDPC));
            KeInitializeDpc (pDpcObject, MyDeferredRoutine, pTimer);
        }

        LARGE_INTEGER dueTime;
        dueTime.QuadPart = -10000 * IDLE_INTERVAL; // 10000 * 10000 * 1 ns
        // "Platoon" timer:
        KeSetTimerEx (pTimer,
                dueTime, // latency relative interval
                (IDLE_INTERVAL / 2), // period of 5 seconds, i.e. 5000 * 1 ms
                pDpcObject);

            if (KeReadStateTimer (pTimer))
            {
                //DbgPrint ("- Example- KeReadStateTimer returns TRUE.");
            }
            else
            {
            //  DbgPrint ("- Example- KeReadStateTimer returns FALSE.");
            }
        }
        Status = KeWaitForSingleObject (pTimer,
                       Executive, // IN KWAIT_REASON WaitReason,
                       KernelMode, // IN KPROCESSOR_MODE WaitMode,
                       FALSE, // IN BOOLEAN Alertable,
                       NULL); // IN PLARGE_INTEGER Timeout OPTIONAL



    RtlInitUnicodeString(&TestName, L"\\??\\C:\\log.txt");

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjAttr, &TestName,
                                OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE,
                                0, NULL);

    Status = NtCreateFile(&TestFile,
                         FILE_WRITE_DATA + SYNCHRONIZE,
                         &ObjAttr,
                         &IoStatus, NULL,
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                         FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                         FILE_OVERWRITE_IF,
                         FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
                         NULL, 0);
  if(Status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
  {
      Status = NtWriteFile(TestFile,
                            0, NULL, NULL,
                            &IoStatus,
                            (PCHAR)"OUR LOG STORED TO LOG FILE",
                            22,
                            NULL, NULL);
  }
  NtClose(TestFile);
    }
```

Comment: At least document the Status code.  Use L"\\\\??\\C:\\log.txt"